# How can I query OSM API by city name

Tags: gis, openstreetmap

I am using Open Street map API to get roads of a city, the problem when I

```
GET /api/0.6/map?bbox=left,right,up,down
```

while the city is not rectangle, how can I make sure that I only query a city.

https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/7444

Comment: You mean you want to download the full osm data set for a city (which is what `GET /api/0.6/map?bbox=left,right,up,down` does for a bounding box)?

Comment: yes, I do can u help

Comment: If you just need the data to be trimmed by the boundary polygon, it might be better to download the entire area from services such as https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts and then post-process the data?